# How to compile (make) in a directory with a hashtag in its name?

Tags: bash, cmake, cygwin

(TL;DR at the bottom)

I have a c++ project which I am able to compile successfully using

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make
```

However, because I didn't want my cloud-synchronization program to sync this, I named this folder not `build`, but `_#build` instead. this caused make to output this:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file make: ***
[Makefile:190: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

After experimenting around with different names for the build folder - `~build~ seems to work for example - I noticed that cmake's output differs by one line when the dirname contains a hashtag (#) sign.

> -- Detecting CXX compile features - failed

Without the hashtag, it says "done" instead of "failed".

For this specific case, I just told my sync tool to also ignore directories that are named "build" and just used the dirname "build", but I am still wondering how I could workaround this if I wanted to keep the hashtag in the name. This is my question: How could I run make successfully within a directory that contains `#` in its name?

Please note that this happened on cygwin and I am not sure whether this would also happen on a native bash shell.

**First Edit**

As suggested by Patrick Kelly, I tried to replace all occurences in the paths within the Makefile from `_#build` to `_\#build`. I did so manually, and after making sure there were no other occurences also using `sed`.
This did not work when I then tried to run `make`, so I tried to just replace every occurence of `_#build` in any file in any subfolder - I figure there won't be any occurences outside of paths. Just to make sure there's nothing left unchanged. So what I did was:

`$ grep --null -l '_#build' -r . | xargs -0 sed -i 's/_#build/_\\#build/g'`

I don't really understand why I had to escape the backslash, I thought single quotes didn't evaluate it. But anyways, this also didn't work. Short explanation of this command: grep lists all filenames (`-l`) of the found occurrences in any subfolder (`-r`) and separates them with nullcharacteres (`--null`) such that xargs applies sed to all of these files. the sed command itself does the replacement for all occurences in a file.

The problem now:

```
make

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.6.2/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:36 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (PROJECT)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_#build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_#build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [Makefile:190: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

And CMakeError.log contains for "Run Build Command" and for "Detecting CXX [-std=c++14] compiler features ..." the following (not pasting the whole thing).
Detecting CXX [-std=c++14] compiler features failed to compile with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_\#build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_1dcec/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_1dcec.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_1dcec.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_\#build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_', needed by 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_1dcec.dir/feature_tests.cxx.o'.  Stop.
```

So apparently, I inserted the backslash at too many places, huh?
The simple solution: I didn't need to change all occurences in my Makefile. What I had to replace:

```
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_\#build"
```

What I had to leave as it was:

```
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/t/_#build/CMakeFiles" "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/t/_#build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks"
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start "/cygdrive/c/Users/Eric/Documents/temp/t/_#build/CMakeFiles" 0
```

Also, no need to change any other files than the Makefile.

> **TL;DR**
>
> Only change the line with `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` to `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR =
>   "/cygdrive/c/Users/myUser/Documents/temp/_\#build"`

Because the path I needed to replace was the first occurrence in the Makefile, the following bash command did the trick for me to automatize it.

```
sed -i 's/_#build/_\\#build/' Makefile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the fact that `make` uses the # sign for comments.  When `cmake` creates your Makefile, one of the lines generated will set the build directory for you.  Something like this:

```
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = "/home/Patrick/TEMP/_#build"
```

But since the # sign is for comments, and `make` does not use all of the same escape rules that your shell does, it ignores the `build"` part of that line.  This creates an non-terminated string. There is no CMake mechanism that will let you fix this automatically.  The user cannot override the definition for CMAKE_BINARY_DIR from the `CMakeLists.txt` file. That's a special variable that `cmake` generates and manages. So the only way to make this work is to manually edit `Makefile` after you run `cmake`, and add an escape character before the # sign:

```
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = "/home/Patrick/TEMP/_\#build"
```

If you're willing to manually edit after the `cmake` command, you can make it work.  Or if you're *really* motivated, you could write your own shell script to make that change to `Makefile` for you, and run the command after `cmake`.  Something like:

```
mkdir _#build && cd _#build
cmake ..
fix_makefile.sh
make
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll accept the answer as soon as I tried it out :) I assume then that nothing else cmake does is dependent on the path? I've never before even looked into a makefile or cmake

Comment: @lucidbrot - I can't swear to it, but I believe that to be correct.  Everything else in the Makefile will refer to the build directory using the variable ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}, so it only needs to be fixed in one place.  That was certainly the case when I tried a simple example yesterday.  One complicating factor, though, for large projects?  If the `cmake` build has lots of subdirectories, and therefore lots of independent Makefiles, *all* of the Makefiles will need to be edited.  For simpler projects, though, this won't be a concern.  Good luck!

Comment: it worked. Anybody else trying, take care to **only** change the line with CMAKE_BINARY_DIR, even if the path appears at other lines too.